# How can the React useContext hook be used to control application and conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm attempting to use React hooks for the first time, and I want to eventually replace the old context API. How do I implement the useContext hooks to accomplish global state?

I have been trying to follow a number of tutorials on Medium, other Stack overflow posts, and some random blog posts. Below is the code I currently have:

APP.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppProvider, useAppValue } from './AppContext';
import FormLogin from './FormLogin';
import FormRegister from './FormRegister';

const App = () => {
  const initialState = {
    page: <FormLogin/>
  }

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'loadLogin':
        return {
          ...state,
          page: <FormLogin/>
        };
      case 'loadRegister':
        return {
          ...state,
          page: <FormRegister/>
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

  let { page } = useAppValue();
  let currentPage = page ? page : <FormLogin/>

  return (
    <AppProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <div className="App">
        {currentPage}
      </div>
    </AppProvider>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

APPCONTEXT.JS

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export const AppContext = createContext();
export const AppProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => (
  <AppContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </AppContext.Provider>
);

export const useAppValue = () => useContext(AppContext);
```

The two Form components are basically dummy components with minimal JSX in them.

I keep getting multiple "TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined" errors. Is this the incorrect way to use the new useContext hook?

Ideally I want each form to have a link that when clicked, changes you to the other form. i.e. If you are at the login form but need to register, it changes to the register form, and if you are on the register form but already have an account, it flips you to the login form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are not using the Reducer Logic of the useContext hook correctly. You must first understand that unless you have a provider in the hierarchy, you won't be able to use the context. Since AppProvider is rendered inside the App you wouldn't be able to use context within App.

Secondly, you must not store the Components as Tags in reducer, if you want, you can store its reference

So your code will finally look like

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppProvider, useAppValue } from './AppContext';
import FormLogin from './FormLogin';
import FormRegister from './FormRegister';

  const initialState = {
    page: FormLogin
  }

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'loadLogin':
        return {
          ...state,
          page: FormLogin
        };
      case 'loadRegister':
        return {
          ...state,
          page: FormRegister
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

const App = () => {
  let [{ page: Page }] = useAppValue();

  return (

      <div className="App">
         <Page />
      </div>
  );
}

export default (props) => (
      <AppProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
          <App {...props} />
      </AppProvider>
)
```

EDIT: Made sure to add array around your page deconstruction.

Comment: I tried to implement this as you had stated here: https://repl.it/@smkarber/New-Hooks, but it doesn't seem to be working. The <Page/> tag you have is not defined.

Comment: @smkarber, A small mistake from my side, it would be `let { page: Page } = useAppValue();`

Comment: thanks for the update. It has a new error, I'll keep trying to figure out what's wrong and see if I can get this to work.

It still doesn't like the <Page/>.

The error is: "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Comment: Sorry for the error again, I missed the reducer part too, It should be `return {
              ...state,
              page: FormLogin
            };` Check the updated answer

Comment: I did that as soon you had suggested that I couldn't pass in Components. It's the same error. Could you look at the repl I linked in my first comment? Maybe you are able to notice it?

Comment: Added a working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-mountain-z4dst. The problem was that useAppValue is returning an array with the first element being the context object and second as the dispatch function, since you want to read page from the first object you would have to write `const [{ page: Page }] = useAppValue();` instead of `const { page: Page } = useAppValue();`

Comment: Thanks, so much. This working now, Shubham. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The use of useContext is wrong. You dont have any Provider in the hierarchy of useContext.

This is the sample way of using reducers that i have implemneted.

In Store.js, to initialise React Context -

```
import {createContext} from 'react';
const Context = createContext();
export default Context;
```

In Reducers.js, the logic for having a common state management system,

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import Context from './Store';

const initialState = {
 count: 0,
 someothervalue: 'hello'
}

function reducer(state, action) {
 const {count, ...otherValues} = state;
 switch(action.type) {
    case 'increment':
        return {count: count + 1, ...otherValues};
    case 'decrement':
        return (count > 0) ? {count: count - 1, ...otherValues} : state;
    default:
        return state;
 }
}

const ReducerProvider = (props) => {
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
 return (<Context.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
    {props.children}
 </Context.Provider>)
}

export default ReducerProvider;
```

In App.js,

```
<ReducerProvider>
  ..... Your Code .....
</ReducerProvider>
```

In Component.js,

```
import Context from '../Store';
....
....
....
const {state, dispatch} = useContext(Context);
return (... your component logic)
```